# Toggle Video permissions using Terminal

Tags: terminal, video, permission, privacy

Is there any way to toggle Privacy Settings using the terminal? The use-case is that for certain meetings I'd like to have the option to toggle video on/off and for others, I want to completely disable the video toggle (by revoking permission), so that video doesn't turn on "accidentally"?

[image]

Comment: Probably easier to phyiscally block the camera if required.

Comment: Well, the end goal is to be able to write a script that reads calendar events and blocks camera for certain events (participants > 10), and keeps it on for daily recurring ones.